# MySQL MAX(datetime) not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve the max(date_entered) for a group of computer_ids.
The first query won't return accurate results.  The second query gives me accurate results but essentially hangs unless I filter by a specific computer_id.

I'd rather use this first query

```
SELECT *, max(reports.date_entered)
FROM reports, hardware_reports
WHERE reports.report_id=hardware_reports.report_id 
GROUP BY computer_id;
```

than this second query

```
SELECT *
FROM reports a
JOIN hardware_reports
ON a.report_id=hardware_reports.report_id 
AND a.date_entered = (
    SELECT MAX(date_entered)
    FROM reports AS b
    WHERE a.computer_id = b.computer_id)
and computer_id = 1648;
```

I need to either optimize second or get max to work in first.

Comment: you should check wheather your datetime field datatype shold be datetime not varcahar or char.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternative join it on a subquery that gets the latest record for every `computer_ID`.

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM    reports a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  computer_ID, MAX(date_entered) date_entered
            FROM    reports
            GROUP   BY computer_ID
        ) b ON  a.computer_ID = b.computer_ID
                AND a.date_entered = b.date_entered
        INNER JOIN hardware_reports c
            ON  a.report_id = c.report_id
```

To make it more efficient, provide an index on columns:

```
ALTER TABLE reports INDEX idx_report_compDate (computer_ID, date_entered)
```

Comment: That was god send. Thanks. (can't add indexes/3rd party app). Thanks again.